# "File is still in use": How to free all resources / force deletion of files?

Tags: r, windows, file, delete-file

**Question:** How to free all file handlers / connections R is using ? In Python, one could have a look which objects are still alive. Is there anything comparable in R?

Within a function, I create a directory with some files. At the end of the function, it should be deleted again. I am facing the problem that I am unable to delete the files, presumably because a file handler is still open. The example is with the MetaSKAT package, but I'm interested in a general solution. The example data can be found here: https://groups.google.com/group/skat_slee/attach/28a76339619d8358/Datasets.zip?part=4&authuser=0

```
# Code author: Seunggeun (Shawn) Lee
setwd('./Datasets')
foo <- function(dir.name) {
  ###### Preparation stuff ################################################
  if (!require(MetaSKAT)) {install.packages('MetaSKAT'); require(MetaSKAT)} 
  dir.create(file.path('.',dir.name),showWarnings=F)
  dir.path <- paste("./",dir.name,sep="")
  file.copy(c("01.fam","01.bed", "01.bim", "01_3.SetID"), dir.path)
  setwd(dir.path)
  FAM<-read.table("01.fam", header=FALSE)
  y<-FAM[,6]
  N.Sample<-length(y)
  x1<-rnorm(N.Sample)
  x2<-rbinom(N.Sample,1, 0.5)
  obj <-SKAT_Null_Model(y~cbind(x1, x2))
  re  <-Generate_Meta_Files(obj, "01.bed", "01.bim", "01_3.SetID", "01.MSSD", "01.MInfo", N.Sample)

  ###### Problem #######################################################
  print(file.remove(list.files(), force = T)) # problem: cannot delete
  # curiously, sometimes there is 1, sometimes 2 False...

  ###### my different tries to solve it ################################
  rm(re)
  closeAllConnections()
  sink.number() # shows 0
  rm(list = ls())
  gc()

  ######  problem is still there  ######################################
  print(file.remove(list.files())) 
  setwd('..')
#   print(unlink(dir.path, recursive = T)) # I want finally delete the directory
}
debug(foo)
foo("temp2")
```

I am using R Studio. Even if a try to delete it manually in Windows while R is still open, it tells me that the file is be used by a program. I can only delete it after I closed R.

So how can I force R to free these files? I will try to solve the problem at the root and look at the source code of Generate_Meta_Files(), but I thought there must be a global function in R which forces to free everything (Note: I am well aware that it does not make sense to create the files and delete it directly afterwards, it's just an example.)

**Edit:** After a hint, I tried it under Linux. It turns out that though it shows me that there was a problem with deletion of one (of the 6) files, all is properly deleted, hence I guess this is a windows-specific problem. Any hints what this is?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in R, but may be this would be useful::
(MoveFileEx) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hm, I do not know if I understand everything in the article. I know that it is possible to include C++ into R, but I never tried it and this depends even on the windows-lib, so even more space for problems. I'll see if I find a more convenient solution, but nevertheless thanks alot!